# Filter/reorder JSON elements in webpage

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I display some data off a JSON file in my webpage, and I'm wondering if it's possible to sort it by type. My webpage is http://nutriton.herokuapp.com/market and the way I display information in that page is like this in my handlebars file:

```
{{#each marketData.marketposts}}
<div class="marketposts">
  <h4>
    {{name}}  ({{type}})
     <br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm upvote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> {{upvotes}}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm downvote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> {{downvotes}}</button>
  </h4>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

I want to be able to press a button and have it filter the data to display only 'Kosher' products, for example. Also, I am also wondering if I can sort the data based on name, etc. Is it possible to do that, if so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to access to each element.

```
var json = '{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

var keys = Object.keys(parsed);
var stop = Object.keys(parsed).length;

for(x = 0; x < stop; x++){
    alert('x: ' + x + ' parse: ' + parsed[keys[x]] + ' key: ' + keys[x]);
}
```

From here you can sort and filter.